# Pip Errors Out When Installing Anything

Tags: python, pip

I've run into an odd issue where pip just won't work. I'm using the latest version of PyCharm, and I've tried both Python 3.8.10 and 3.9.6.
I've done clean installations of both, removed from PATH, reinstalled with new installer, reinstalled pip, etc.
The error code I run into appears no matter what library I am trying to download. I've tried `PyAudio`, `PyGame`, `OpenCV-Python` and others.
Pip was working fine a couple days ago, and no changes have been made to any files in that time.
Attempting to run `pip install --upgrade pip` does not have an effect.

I've been running off virtual enviroments with `setuptools 40.8.0` and `pip 21.1.3` installed.

The full error for installing `PyAudio` can be seen here: https://pastebin.com/iQmZwsRv

PyGame error: https://pastebin.com/WEF8uM2d

OpenCV-Python Error: https://pastebin.com/LuZq99Cu

Comment: In the case of pyaudio, it seems like the library is only compatible up to python 3.6, and I get a similar error on my copy of python 3.9. Is the message equivalent for the other libraries you mentioned, or is it failing for another reason in those cases?

Comment: It is not the same message, but they all stopped working at the same time and I assume can be attributed to pip. I will try installing PyAudio on a 3.6 version.
I've edited the original post with the error for `Pygame` and `OpenCV-Python`.

Comment: Yep, looks like the issue was mismatched versions on all of them, with different errors. Moving to 3.6.8 fixed the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Py- audio` - it's not compatible with your **Py charm** I suppose due to the latest install updates, try to install it on the main environment. Also, try to downgrade your version of python as many dependencies are not compatible with your version of python as stated by error[`it is not compatible with this Python`]

`Open Cv` - Fails to build the wheel package as it is attributed also in error [`CMake was unable to find a build program corresponding to "Ninja".  CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM is not set.  You probably need to select a different build tool.`]

May I know what build tool are you using?

Comment: It should be using pip's wheels.
As for downgrading, that was indeed the issue. Moving back to 3.6.8 and installing allowed me to download all of them. I assume this is an issue with the libraries not being updated to 3.9
Thanks!

Comment: HAve a great time